# HAML app layout not being picked up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm working on my 1st Ruby on Rails app.  I have set up HAML as my formatter and it is rendering views fine.
  However, I have a views/layouts/application.html.haml file for the basic layout, but it is not being picked up at all.  All I see on the page is may view's HTML.
  What could make this fail to be picked up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your controller extends `ApplicationController` and not `ActionController::Base`.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: This did fix it.  I'll check this out in more detail.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you assert that application.html.erb has been removed from the app/views/layouts directory?